# Is it possible to use Trello with incoming email integration?

Tags: trello, email, integration

It would be nice to have a mail address to send messages to that are then  'automagically' added to a Trello list on a specified board. So it could be used for some sort of issue tracking.

Is it / will it be possible somehow?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this for free with [this Zap](https://zapier.com/zapbook/email/trello/424/email-to-trello-creates-card/) via [Zapier](https://zapier.com/).

[image: Email to Trello]

Disclosure: I am on of the founders at Zapier, but I use this on a daily basis and would even if I wasn't the founder. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible with a tool like [Emello](http://www.emelloapp.com/).

> Send your email straight to Trello with Emello. You get dedicated custom email addresses for each of your Trello boards. Start sending email to Trello today.

Answer (score 2):

This is now a feature in trello. Just click on "Email-to-board Settings".

http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1216141-creating-cards-by-email

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Gmail to Trello Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-to-trello/oceoildfbiaeclndnjknjpfaoofeekgl?hl=ru), working good and easy to use.